# Amazon S3 vs Window Azure Blob Storage

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I went through the docs of both Azure and Amazon S3, but I confused about few things - 
Both of these try to solve the same question i.e, storage on the cloud. Now My Question here is that **when to use what?** i.e., when is it preferred to use Azure and when Amazon S3 is preferred. I googled about it hard and couldn't find any substantial resource for the same. I would really appreciate if some one could enlighten me regarding the same.

**EDIT:**

I want to consider following params as the base for choosing my cloud provider -

1) Latency 
2) Scalability 
3) Size of each file 
4) Cost & Performance 
5) Files which are can be accessed quite randomly.

These are few params I have considered. It would be great if you can provide additional Params to consider.

Comment: The question is at very high level. Even your words "Storage on Cloud" doesn't help. What exactly you are trying to store ? From where you are going to access those, from where you are going to push the data ? What is the scale / data size ? All those needs to be considered to come to a conclusion. At a high level, we can tell that, both can be used for Storage. It depends on where exactly is your servers located ? It makes sense for you to keep the affinity as less as possible for latency and cost.

Comment: Kindly elaborate your question, you might get good answers, with the current question, chances are it might be "closed"

Comment: I have edited my Question please check

Answer (score 3):

There are many studies online. You should evaluate it by yourself based on your workload and scenario.

One of many reports, says that Azure is good at small files: http://www.nasuni.com/resource/the-state-of-cloud-storage-in-2013 
Under my understanding, this is because Azure blob is designed to be an unified storage, so it optimize for small block access. Conversely, S3 is originate from web storage.

On the other hand, S3 is good at scale up, since Azure has limitation per account.

Comment: Your link is behind a paywall.  Please find an alternative.